# Show WebAPI View from Stored Procedure in Angular 7 application

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

is there a way to show my View, which I generated inside of my WebAPI Project in my Angular 7 application?

I already wrote the c# code in my controller, but the api isn't even shown inside swagger.

```cs
public IEnumerable<Apt> ShortLow()
{
    List<Apt> emplist = new List<Apt>();
    using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
    {
        var results = db.Fun_SL().ToList();
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            var apts = new Apt()
            {
                AptID = result.AptID,
                EyrieID= result.EyrieID,
                symbol = result.symbol,
                isin = result.isin,

            };
            emplist.Add(apts);
        }
        return emplist;
    }
}
```

The code to display it directly in the WebAPI is as easy as

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DBModel sd = new DBModel();

    return View(sd.Fun_SL());
}
```

in the home.controller and

```html
@model IEnumerable<WebAPI.Models.Apt>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>symbol</th>
        <th>isin</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var result in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@result.symbol</td>
        <td>@result.isin</td>

    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

in the Index.cshtml

Comment: Normally your angular app doesn't start like this. Your angular app should represent angular module. Register your client side controllers in that module. Expose controller get methods to feed the data at index page. Continuing in preparing sample answer for you...

Comment: You should create independent angular project by angular CLI and add service.ts and use HttpClient to call your API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANGULAR
display in html

```
<table>
      <tr>
          <th>symbol</th>
          <th>isin</th>
      </tr>

      <tr *ngFor="let emp of service.list">
          <td>{{emp.symbol}}</td>
          <td>{{emp.isin}}</td>
      </tr>

</table>
```

typescript display

```
export class AptListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: AptService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.refreshList();
  }

  populateForm(emp: Apt) {
    this.service.formData = Object.assign({}, emp);
  }

}
```

typescript service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Apt } from './Apt.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AptService {

  formData: Apt;
  list: Apt[];
  readonly rootURL = 'http://localhost:50389/api';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  refreshList() {
    this.http.get(this.rootURL + '/ShortLow')
      .toPromise().then(res => this.list = res as Apt[]);
  }

}
```

WebAPI
corrected controller:

```
     [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Apt> ShortLow()
        {
            List<Apt> emplist = new List<Apt>();
            using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
            {
                var results = db.Fun_SL().ToList();
                foreach (var result in results)
                {
                    var apts = new Apt()
                    {
                        AptID = result.AptID,
                        EyrieID= result.EyrieID,
                        symbol = result.symbol,
                        isin = result.isin,

                    };
                    emplist.Add(apts);
                }
                return emplist;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Server Side :**

```
 public LowController : ApiController
 {

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult<IEnumerable<Apt>> ShortLow()
    {
        List<Apt> emplist = new List<Apt>();
        using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
        {
            var results = db.Fun_SL().ToList();
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                var apts = new Apt()
                {
                    AptID = result.AptID,
                    EyrieID= result.EyrieID,
                    symbol = result.symbol,
                    isin = result.isin,

                };
                emplist.Add(apts);
            }
            return emplist;
        }
    }
```

**Clientside : Index.html**

```html
<html>
<body ng-app="shortLowApp" ng-controller="shortLowController">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Symbol</th>
            <th>isin</th>
        </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in symbols">
                <td>{{ data.symbol }}</td>
                <td>{{ data.isin }}</td>
            </tr>        
    </table>

    <script src="Scripts/lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**ClientSide : app.js**

```
// <reference path="lib/angular.js" />

var shortLowApp = angular.module('shortLowApp', []);

var shortLowController = shortLowApp.controller('shortLowController', function 
($scope, $http) {

        $scope.symbols =  [
        {
            "symbol": "1",
            "isin": "Super Cateogry"

        },

        {
            "symbol": "2",
            "isin": "Top Cateogry"

        },

        {
            "symbol": "3",
            "isin": "Sample Cateogry"

        },

        {
            "symbol": "4",
            "isin": "Product Cateogry"
        }
    ];

    // for producing above array, return a JSON array from your Server side Angular Controller method by using http.Get call.

        //$http.get("https://localhost:44370/api/low/ShortLow").then(function (symbolData) {
    //    $scope.symbols = symbolData.symbols;
    //});
So, un comment above HTTP get call and comment the hardcoded array. Make sure, you have some controller at Web api side, which produces the data.

     });
```

Let me know if you find any difficulty in producing the output what you wanted.
The above code produces the following ouput at my side.

[image]

Comment: The OP is using Angular 7, not AngularJS.

Comment: then, OP need to use Typescript and components based strategy rather than above AngularJS specific code. But I believe, he should use Microsoft SPA template with angular CLI application within that.

Comment: I just have provided the idea, not the 100% corresponding implementation for Angular 7. But OP has to do the same for angular 7 just by considering directives and components methodology.

Comment: Hello, Usman thank you for your answer. I will try to implement it